# Visual Studio Blazor: Encountered end tag "br" with no matching start tag

Tags: html, .net-core, blazor

I'm familiar with the perils of not closing tags, but my understanding is that `<br />` should be self-closing?

```
@if (students != null) // Insert form
{
    <input placeholder="First Name" @bind="@firstName" /></br />
    <input placeholder="Last Name" @bind="@lastName" /></br />
    <input placeholder="School" @bind="@school" /></br />
    <button @onclick="@Insert" class="btn btn-warning">Insert</button>
}
```

results in error `RZ1026    Encountered end tag "br" with no matching start tag.  Are your start/end tags properly balanced?`

Visual Studio 2019 v16.7.2, dotnet core v3.1.401

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`</br />` - two slashes. Looks like VisualStudio was trying to help.

Comment: might be worth including the correct form of that tag for people wondering why it is wrong